# /wp-admin/ is redirected to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wp-admin

A friend of mine asked me to help him with his website. When he goes to /wp-admin/ he doesn't see the login screen but returns to the homepage. I've disabled the plugins one by one dut that didn't help. Also the menu items to the other pages aren't working. Now Im checking the .htaccess file but my knowledge on that is limited:

`

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.*.[pP][hH].* index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^.*.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] index.php [L]

`

I know the ReWriteEngine should be on but is the rest correct?

Update: looks like the site is hacked, so working on that one now

Thanks in advance

John

Tried to go to websitename/wp-admin/ I expected the inlogscreen but Ive kept returning to the homepage.

Comment: You should give more information. But try to use the default WordPress [htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) and test it. Of course, don't forget to backup the file before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess îs wrong, seems like a hack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).